# Importing opcua xml files

Tags: python, xml, opc-ua

when i am importing OPC UA devices, OPCUA machinery , and OPCUA pump , gertting this error : Parsing value of type 'QualifiedName' not implemented

here is the code i am using :
    `from opcua import ua, Server # Create server server = Server() # Set server endpoint url = "opc.tcp://10.220.1.163:4140" server.set_endpoint(url) # Set server name server.set_server_name("OPC UA Server") server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Di.NodeSet2.xml") server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Machinery.Nodeset2.xml") server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Pumps.NodeSet2.xml") server.import_xml("NetschPump.xml") server.start()`
can somebody tell me what is the error ? i have been trying to solve since 2 days, but did not find any       clue. your advices and solution would be appreciated.

I have tried to importing all files together, but it causes an error always.

Comment: You have an issue with the namespace inside the xml.  See : https://opclabs.doc-that.com/files/onlinedocs/QuickOpc/Latest/User%27s%20Guide%20and%20Reference-QuickOPC/OPC%20UA%20Qualified%20Names.html?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1):

Switch to [asyncua](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio). The asyncua library is active mantained and has a lot of fixes reagarding xml import. If the error is also in asyncua, open a issue there  with minimal example and I will have a look a the problem.

Comment: even i tried with asyncua , still it occurs an same error :  raise UaStatusCodeError(self.value)
asyncua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadNodeIdExists: "The requested node id is already used by another node."(BadNodeIdExists)
FYI : I have created custom_nodeset2.xml using siemens SiOME modelling editor.

Comment: There is a error in the nodeset. A nodeid is used mutlitple times that is what the error says. Open a issue in asyncua and add the nodeset + minimal example and i will have a look at it.

Comment: here is the code : from asyncua import ua, Server
import asyncio
async def main():
    server = Server()
    await server.init()     
    server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://192.168.1.216:4000")
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Nodeset2.xml")
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Di.Nodeset2.xml")
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Machinery.Nodeset2.xml")
    await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Pumps.Nodeset2.xml")
    await server.import_xml("testing_Nodeset.xml")
    await server.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Comment: Make a issue in asyncua and add a full stacktrace, log output and the testing_Nodeset.xml.